# jQuery Mobile not working with MVC RedirectResult

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile on an MVC 3 website. Working well except that I have an  tag that links to a controller action that returns a RedirectResult. It looks like jQuery is intercepting the link and it errors out every time. I get the standard "An error has occurred" message that the mobile framework outputs. Inspecting the response with Firebug shows the response is totally empty.

I've heard there might be a data- attribute I need to add to the  tag to make the mobile UI ignore it? Any ideas on that or other solutions?

**EDIT:** Just for clarification, the URL is being generated correctly and is a valid URL, it has something to do with the way jQUery mobile is intercepting the request.

```
<a href='/fullsite?p=@Request.ServerVariables["URL"]' title="view full site" >view full site</a>

public RedirectResult FullSite()
                {
                    StringBuilder redirectUrl = new StringBuilder("http://www.site.com/");

                    try
                    {
                        string referringUrl = Request.QueryString["p"];

                        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(referringUrl) && referringUrl.Contains("photo-gallery"))
                            referringUrl = referringUrl.Replace(@"/photo-gallery", String.Empty);

                        redirectUrl.Append(referringUrl);
                    }
                    catch (Exception)
                    {
                        redirectUrl.Clear();
                        redirectUrl.Append("http://www.site.com");
                    }

                    CookieManager.SetMobileToFullSiteCookie();
                    return new RedirectResult(redirectUrl.ToString());
                }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use `rel="external"` to force links to load as a normal request instead of using AJAX.

```
<a href='/fullsite?pRequest.ServerVariables["URL"]'
   rel="external"
   title="view full site" >view full site</a>
```

You can also use `data-ajax="false"` or set a value for `target`, see the docs for 1.0a3 at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a3/docs/pages/link-formats.html

Comment: I think I like data-ajax better. Seems more jQuery mobile-ish. :)

Comment: @Scott, for an actual internal link that you want to simply reload afresh, I agree.  My use case is actually an external link and `rel="external"` is more semantically correct.